# Variables passed by reference to static method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have some code that is behaving like my variables are being passed by reference when I don't think they should be.

In a class library I have

```
public class ListingHelper
{
    public static List<FilterCategory> getListingFilterCertifications(ListingCategory parentListingCategory, ListingFilters filters)
    {
       ...//Building up return object
       filters.gradingServiceId = 2;
    }

}
```

In the pageLoad of a page I call this:

```
private void BindForm()
{
   ListingFilters filters = new ListingFilters();
   filters.gradingServiceId = 0;

   if (filters.gradingServiceId > 0)
   {
       listCertification.DataSource = ListingHelper.getListingFilterCertificationById(filters.gradingServiceId);
       listCertification.DataBind();
   }
}
```

I thought that `filters.gradingServiceId` should be 0 when I get back from calling my method in the library, but it's coming back as 2. Are methods parameters to static methods really passed by reference?

Listing Filters:

```
public class ListingFilters
{
    public String state { get; set; }
    public int categoryId { get; set; }
    public int gradingServiceId { get; set; }
    public int gradeId { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**

Thanks for the link Jon. So it sounds like in .net all user created classes are reference types and even when passed by value you aren't actually sending a copy of the object but instead a pointer to its location in memory.

If that's the case how would I pass a copy of my filters object to a method so that I can mess around with the values and have them not be affected in the code that called it?

Comment: you are infact overwriting the gradingServiceId to 2,inside the  static method

Comment: Please read http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: Looks like some confusion between `getListingFilterCertifications` and `getListingFilterCertificationById`.

Comment: Thanks for the link jon, could you see the small edit I made to my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have conceptualized what pass by reference or pass by value in C# means.  If you read the specification:

> A value parameter is used for input parameter passing. A value parameter corresponds to a local variable that gets its initial value from the argument that was passed for the parameter. Modifications to a value parameter do not affect the argument that was passed for the parameter.
>
> Value parameters can be optional, by specifying a default value so that corresponding arguments can be omitted.
>
> A reference parameter is used for both input and output parameter passing. The argument passed for a reference parameter must be a variable, and during execution of the method, the reference parameter represents the same storage location as the argument variable. A reference parameter is declared with the ref modifier. The following example shows the use of ref parameters.

What is probably confusing you here is when you pass reference type as a value parameter a copy of the object is not made a copy of the pointer to the object is made.  So if you make a modification to the object inside the method it will be on the actual object not a copy.  Why this is considered pass by value is that the pointer is the value that is being passed.  If however, you reassigned the parameter to another object (i.e. change the pointer) this will not persist outside the method unless your parameter is declared with the ref keyword.

Comment: You are munging concepts.  ListingFilters is a reference type because it is a class (if it was a struct it'd be a value type).  Ignoring value types for now because they are slightly different, but not relevant here.  The reference to the object is passed by value by default, but the object isn't really passed at all to a method just the reference (i.e. the pointer). So when talking about passed by value you are talking about the reference being passed by value. This means that even though that pointer is copied it points to the same memory location and thereby effectively passing by reference

Comment: Thanks, It sounds like I didn't have a good understanding of how parameters in .net worked.

Answer (score 7):

All parameters are passed by value. `ListingFilters` is a Reference Type, it points to an object in heap memory, so it's "value" is a memory address. When you pass it to a function as a parameter the parameter's "value" is a reference to the same object.

Comment: Thanks, could you take a look at my edit to the question and see if I have it right?

Answer (score 1):

Arguments in C# are passed by value whether in static, non static, generic methods. 
The references are also passed by value. 
Since ListingFilters is an object, it is passed by value reference if that makes sense. And so you are overwriting the value as the reference argument passed in points to a valid memory location.

Answer (score 0):

- A copy is made for both value type and reference Type.
- In case of value type,the actual value is copied and is local to that
  method.Any changes you make is not visible outside the method.
- But in case of a Reference Type,a copy is made of the address.So
  there is just one object ,but two copies of the address.Any change that you make to the   object through the local copy inside of the method is visible outside.